Running a console application (CLI) from docker-compose
Have java code:
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter Name");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + s);
    }
}

Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY /src/Hello.java /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN ["javac", "Hello.java"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "Hello"]

docker_compose.yml
version: "3.0.0"

name: ar
services:
  app:
    build: .

I would like to launch an application from docker-compose and interact with it.
I tried:

enter to the terminal application

docker compose up -d docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash
but this gave me access to the container's terminal, not the application's. Therefore, the "java Hello" command had to be duplicated manually

enter to the terminal application

docker-compose logs container_id 
but this did not allow me to enter text

change docker_compose.yml
 version: "3.0.0"
 name: app
 services:
   mav:
     build: .
     stdin_open: true
     tty: true



but this left me with a locked console at the text entry point

change docker-compose versions


Try with:
set -e # Exit on any error

container_id=<YOUR_CONTAINER_ID>

echo "Starting container..."

docker-compose up -d 

until [ "$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} ${container_id})" == "true" ]; do
    echo "Waiting for container running..."
    sleep 1
done

echo "Digging into container..."

docker exec -it ${container_id} /bin/bash


docker exec was already mentioned in the question as not working. How will this enter into the running Java process?

All files were written correctly.
Just to run you need three commands, the last two in one line:
'docker compose up -d'  
'docker logs container_id ; docker attach container_id'

